# Filter TYPO3 results in repository

Tags: typo3

When querying the repository using a criteria, it returns an object with multiple result sets. Each result set is an object mapped to the model. So one can get the preferred result set using `->offsetGet()`. How can I get the preferred result set(s) using a parameter value instead?

Example:
A table has three fields `uid`, `guide_option` and `fact`. Table contains multiple records and is mapped to its model. Query fetches data using field `guide_option` and returns several rows:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();

$constraints = [$query->equals('guide_option', $guideOption)];

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));

$resultsets = $query->execute();

#filter by offset
$offset = $resultsets->offsetGet(0);

#filter by fact
$set = ???
```

How does one filter by field `fact`?

Comment: Can you add more details and some example code please?

Comment: @MathiasBrodala Hi Mathias. Just added it.